# How to increase the height of UITextView when Text is more than Height

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitextview

I have a UITextView and when i am entering data into that after 5-6 lines , the data is scrolling up and it cannot be seen. Is there any property that i can use to increase the height of UITextView as the text are entered more than height.

Pls suggest guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to make the height of the UITextView be the same as the height of the content inside it.

```
CGRect frame = _textView.frame;
frame.size.height = _textView.contentSize.height;
_textView.frame = frame;
```